# Jquery DatePicker with multiple dates select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm working on jquery DatePicker here I want to select multiple dates I tried by using `selectMultiple: true` but not achieve. I don't want to use other plugins.
Can anyone help me out how should I get these required result.[DatePicker jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/MehrajKhan/ben1374z/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a datepicker example</p>
  <form>
    Date:
    <input id="datepicker">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery must be included before the library, you need to swap the relevant lines:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Also, try to use a more modern version, we're at 3 now ;-)

As for the question: this datepicker seems to not support date ranges so you're forced to use two input fields with two datepickers.

Mind you I've never used this particular datepicker myself, I've just read its documentation.
This pull request on GitHub gives you some hints:
[Request for ranges enhancement](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/issues/139)

Comment: thanks.but you didn't understand my question I got the datePicker.but here I want to select multiple dates.

Comment: I understood your request but the datepicker didn't work at all to begin with, you got an error for undefined object. I'm modifying my answer with the other part.

Comment: I update my question. I added jsfiddle check. Here I want to select two dates in the same DatePicker.